# Extraer 2 archivos de imagen satelital en una lista dentro de ".tar.gz"

Tags: python, windows, cmd, imagen

Tengo una lista de imágenes satelitales Landsat. Dentro del archivo tar.gz se encuentran las bandas

ej: Archivo "*LC08018051fecha.tar.gz*"
Contiene:

> LC08_fecha_band1.tif
>   LC08_fecha_band2.tif
>   LC08_fecha_band3.tif
>   LC08_fecha_band4.tif
>   LC08_fecha_band5.tif
>   LC08_fecha_band6.tif
>   LC08_fecha_band7.tif
>   LC08_fecha_azimuth_band4.tif
>   LC08_fecha_zenith_band4.tif
>   LC08_fecha_pixel_qa.tif
>   LC08_fecha_aerosol.tif

Necesito **extraer de todos los archivos** .tar.gz **solo** ***LC08_fecha_band3.tif*** y ***LC08_fecha_band4.tif*** para calcular un índice.

El siguiente código funciona para un archivo en específico, extrayendo todo lo que diga band

```
fileName = "LC08018051fecha.tar.gz"
tfile = tarfile.open(fileName, 'r:gz')
membersList = tfile.getmembers()
namesList = tfile.getnames()
bandsList = [x for x, y in zip(membersList, namesList) if "band" in y]
print("extracting...")
tfile.extractall("folder/",members=bandsList)
print ("Done")
```

**Necesito hacerlo genérico para todos los tar.gz dentro de una carpeta y solo extraer la banda 3 y 4.**

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre que podrías utilizar `glob` para filtrar los archivos y luego recorrer cada uno, por ejemplo algo así:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('LC*.tar.gz')
if not files: 
   raise Exception('No se han encontrado archivos a procesar')

for fileName in files:
    tfile = tarfile.open(fileName, 'r:gz')
    membersList = tfile.getmembers()
    namesList = tfile.getnames()
    bandsList = [x for x, y in zip(membersList, namesList) if "band" in y]
    print("extracting...")
    tfile.extractall("folder/",members=bandsList)
    print ("Done")
```

Comment: Funciona eliminando el if not. Ahora debo solucionar la elección de bandas en específico. Gracias

Comment: @OSCAR_P si una respuesta resuelve tu problema deberias considerar aceptarla para mostrar su utilidad a otros usuarios y agradecer el trabajo de quien te la proporciona, puedes mirate [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas) para saber como hacerlo. El `if not` es correcto, solo había un error tipográfico al faltar los dos puntos al final del condicional (Patricio he editado para corregirlo). Saludos.

Comment: @FJSevilla correcto, gracias

Comment: @OSCAR_P para buscar bandas concretas basta con alterar el condicinal a la hora de crear `bandsList`, usar [expresiones regulares](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) puede ser una buena solución para ello. Por ejemplo `r"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+_band[3|4].tif$"` te debería funcionar para capturar solo las bandas 3 y 4.